# passing data to viewcontrollers

Tags: ios

I have a mutable array of values used in a tableviewcontroller, a mapviewcontroller, and the callingviewcontroller.  I have been updating them all, ie.

```
[dataArray addObject:object atIndex:0];
[tvc. dataArray addObject:object atIndex:0];
[mvc. dataArray addObject:object atIndex:0];
```

Is there a way of declaring dataArray in the table and map viewcontrollers that would make them pointers to the dataArray in the callingViewController?  So I would just have to update one?

***Okay guys, I made a really stupid mistake here.  At some point I changed the initialization and passed nil as the dataArray, and for some reason I had an "if (!dataArray) create new" clause to hide it from myself.

Kaan is correct. 
    [dataArray addObject:object atIndex:0];
is all that is needed.

Comment: who owns these view controllers? App delegate ? your rootView controller ?

Comment: the callingviewcontroller owns the tableviewcontroller and mapviewcontroller

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After your comment:

How about you declare a property called `dataArray` in both your tableView and mapView and also callingView. Then, in your callingViewController, you initialize a mutable array called lets say myFirstArray and do:

```
NSMutableArray *myFirstArray = [NSMutableArray array];
self.dataArray = myFirstArray;
myTableView.dataArray = myFirstArray;
myMapView.dataArray = myFirstArray;
```

This way they will both be pointing to the same object and change you do in one will reflect in the other. Give it a try!

Answer (score 1):

This is a little more involved but I think would be the best solution.  You should have some way for all of these different ViewControllers to reference a single object that is managing your data.  This could be a delegate, or it could be a singleton that owns the main dataArray.

Search here or on google for both of those terms and you should be able to get started with either route.

Answer (score 0):

if you create the array in the AppDelegate class then you can access from any other classes within your app.